# Invoking a singleton class to keep a sockets connection open

Tags: iphone, ios, class, singleton

I have created a singleton class whose job is to create a tcp socket connection and keep it open infinitely while the application is running.  I believe my singleton class looks as it's supposed to (with help from other StackOverflow questions to get me there) but my problem is that I do not know WHEN or HOW to invoke my class object.  I'm still pretty new to iOS development, so this is all pretty foreign to me.

- My app has multiple views
- I want to use my singleton class to create a tcp socket connection and keep the connection open at all times
- I do not know WHERE to call/invoke my singleton class object
- I do not know HOW to call/invoke my singleton class object
- I am using the SmallSockets library

Here are my class files:

SocketConnection.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SocketConnection : NSObject
{

}

+ (SocketConnection *)getInstance;

@end
```

SocketConnection.m

```
#import "SocketConnection.h"
#import "imports.h"

static SocketConnection *sharedInstance = nil;

@implementation SocketConnection

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) 
    {
        while(1)
        {
            Socket *socket;
            int port = 11005;
            NSString *host = @"199.5.83.63";

            socket = [Socket socket];

            @try
            {
                NSMutableData *data;
                [socket connectToHostName:host port:port];
                [socket readData:data];
                //  [socket writeString:@"Hello World!"];

                // Connection was successful //
                [socket retain]; // Must retain if want to use out of this action block.
            }
            @catch (NSException* exception) 
            {
                NSString *errMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[exception reason]];
                NSLog(errMsg);
                socket = nil;
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}

+ (SocketConnection *)getInstance
{
    @synchronized(self) 
    {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) 
        {
            sharedInstance = [[SocketConnection alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use this Singleton, and the connection associated with it, you could simply call the getInstance method to get a reference to the connection that your trying to use. You would effectively do this instead of the typical alloc/init process. You can use the getInstance method from each of your views, and they will all maintain the same connection as you are intending.

Also, because the way you create the Singleton, if you call alloc/init instead of getInstance, you WILL create a new connection instead of using the previous one.

An example of how you might do this to create a reference within a view would be:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SocketConnection * connection
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    connection = [SocketConnection getInstance];
}
```

Code similar to this would cause all of your views to use the same connection, but WOULD NOT create the connection until you had a view onscreen that is using the connection. To create the connection at application startup, add this same 'getInstance' to one of your appDelegate methods.

Also, because you are using a singleton, and this variable is never really released, you may want to consider adding methods to reinitialize, remove and generally manage the connection to the server.

Comment: Also agree with your comments, the way he has implemented the getInstance methode will essentially properly initialize the singlton the first time of NEED.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating with a code sample?  This sounds like the way I should go, but I'm not sure I understand how the code would look like.  I'd appreciate any help I could get.  Thanks!

Comment: @Skizz Updated answer to provide requested details.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!  I apologize for the ignorance, but I'm still scratching my head a little bit.  I think I can live with creating a new connection when each view is loaded.  If I chose to go down this route, where would I put the property line and where would I put the awakeFromNib method? Currently, I put the @property line in SocketConnection.h and I put the method definition in my "Main" view's .m file.  I am getting an error, however, "Unknown type name 'connection', did you mean NSConnection?"  Again, I apologize for the ignorance and I appreciate your patience :)

Comment: Ah, I have actually seemed to semi-fix it.  I placed my property in my "Main" view's .h file.  I then synthesized it in my .m file.  Now when I compile, I get the following errors:  1. Unknown type name 'SocketConnection' 2. Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type.  These errors are in my header file on the "property (nonatomic, strong) SocketConnection *connection;" line.  Any clarification would be appreciated.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Skizz The 'SocketConnection' is meant to be your singleton class that you are using. So just import the header for that class. Both these errors should be cleaned up once your import is right.

Comment: Oddly, I was imported SocketConnection.h into a header file called imports.h and when I imported imports.h, it didn't seem to work.  importing SocketConnection.h directly worked just fine.  I still haven't gotten this code to work 100%, but I think I'm far enough along now that I should be able to figure it out from here.  Thanks so much for the help!  Very High Quality!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably perform the initialization in the UIApplication Delegate method

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

This way the connection is initiated and began and you can perform your initialization prior to any of your Views or ViewController coming front or being active.